# Get tax rate separately for every cart and order items in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax-rate

I'd like to modify the cart display (and later the invoice) so that there is another column showing the tax and tax rate for each product. I have not found a function or a getter for the tax rate as a number, only the name, with $_product->get_tax_class(). I was looking for a function like $_product->get_tax_rate() but found none. So I wrote a terrible workaround in  woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php.

After the easy part of adding

```
<th class="product-tax"><?php esc_html_e( 'Tax', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

in Line 35, I added from Line 121:

```
$tax_name = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_tax', $_product->get_tax_class(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
if ($tax_name == "reduced-tax-rate") $tax_rate= 7; else $tax_rate= 19;                      
$with_tax = $_product->get_price( $_product ); 
$without_tax = $with_tax/((100+$tax_rate)/100);
$tax = $with_tax-$without_tax;
$tax = $tax*$cart_item['quantity'];
$tax = number_format($tax, 2, '.', '')." €";
echo "  ".$tax." (".$tax_rate."%)";
```

This works for now, but only in Germany, and it would of course not survive for a very long time. So, what is the better way to do this?

Thanks!

UPDATE

Just found half of the solution:

```
$tax_name = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_tax', $_product->get_tax_class(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
if ($tax_name == "reduced-tax-rate") $tax_rate= 7; else $tax_rate= 19;                      
echo "  ".$cart_item['line_subtotal_tax']." (".$tax_rate."%)";
```

$cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'] holds the value I was trying to get by calculation. Now just the name is missing..."19%" or "7%"...

Answer (score 2):

**2020 October Update** *(removed some mistakes - Tested on WooCommerce 4.5.x version)*

I suppose that `woocommerce_cart_item_tax` is a custom hook as I didn't find it…

The taxes depends on your settings which are one or multiple tax classes and for each tax classes:

- all countries or/and by countries
- all states of a country or/and by state
- all postcodes of a country or/and by postcode
- one or multiple tax rates.
- *(and other settings)*

Now to handle taxes in a correct way you will use [the `WC_Tax` object Class and all related methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Tax.html). We will use here only country based tax rates:

```
 // Getting an instance of the WC_Tax object
 $wc_tax = new WC_Tax();

// Get User billing country
$billing_country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();

// Get the item tax class (your code)
$tax_class = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_tax', $_product->get_tax_class(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

// Get the related Data for Germany and "default" tax class
$tax_data = $wc_tax->find_rates( array('country' => $billing_country, 'tax_class' => $tax_class ) );

// Get the rate (percentage number)
if( ! empty($tax_data) ) {
    $tax_rate = reset($tax_data)['rate'];

    // Display it
    printf( '<span class="tax-rate">' . __("The tax rate is %s", "woocommerce") . '</span>',  $tax_rate . '%' );
}
```

Tested and works.

---

**For orders** *(pdf invoice)* it should be something very similar, where you will need to replace this line:

```
// Get the item tax class (your code)
$tax_class = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_tax', $_product->get_tax_class(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

by something like (where `$item` is the instance of  the `WC_Order_Item_Product` object):

```
// Get the WC_Product Object instance
$_product = $item->get_product();

// Get the item tax class
$tax_class = $_product->get_tax_class();
```